# Логика работы при поиске внутри geoQuery

Tags: yandex-maps-api, filter

Мне нужно применять несколько логических операторов при запросе фильтра, например:

```
let result = ymaps.geoQuery(Collection);
result.search(filter).setOptions(optionSet);
```

на данном этапе используется фильтр следующего содержания:

```
properties.freq != 5555
```

я же хочу искать в пределах от 5500 до 5600. 
Как правильно сконструировать фильтр с логикой:

```
properties.freq >= 5500 and properties.freq <= 5600
```

Спасибо за ответ, однако фильтр работает лишь внутри диапазона, если я хочу выбрать за пределами его, т.е. менее 5500, но более 5600 - фильтр не отрабатывает, для меня это странно. Есть идеи почему так?

```
result.search(function (x) {
        return x.properties.get('freq') >= 5500 &&
            x.properties.get('freq') <= 5600;
}).getLength()
```

возвратит 140

```
result.search(function (x) {
    return x.properties.get('freq') >= 5600 &&
        x.properties.get('freq') <= 5500;
}).getLength()
```

возвратит 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GeoQueryResult#search](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/#method_detail__search-param-condition) принимает фильтр вида `<поле> <операция> <значение>` или любую функию.

```
result.search(function (x) {
  return x.properties.get('freq') >= 5500 &&
    x.properties.get('freq') <= 5600;
}).setOptions(options)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает :) Немного дополнил вопрос, потому что работает немного неожиданно, фильтрует только внутри диапазона, если поменять границы местами - не работает.

Comment: Камраду спасибо, особенно в другом посте, вот что бывает, когда внимание рассеивается и не вижу элементарных вещей...Стыдно :)

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил из документации более элегантный способ, не припомню, чтобы он был при первом прочтении:

```
result.search("properties.freq >= 5500").search("properties.freq <= 5600").getLength();
```

Однако, он все равно работает лишь внутри диапазона... Придется применять исключительные свойства ко всей коллекции и затем применять к диапазону нужные свойства, а еще придется следить за всем этим, если захочется откатить изменения.

Comment: Используйте логическое ИЛИ. Число не может быть одновременно меньше 5500 и больше 5600. `return x.properties.get('freq') >= 5600 || x.properties.get('freq') <= 5500;`

Comment: Вот я совсем замылил глаз...ведь верно! Спасибо за помощь!